# Subtract days/hours/... from the current time in Angular 2

Tags: angular, date, npm

I need to subtract days/hours/minutes from the current time. To do this and following npmjs website, I have done this installation: `npm install --save add-subtract-date` .
Then inside the TS file, I have such a code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

const addSubtractDate = require('add-subtract-date');
let d = new Date(); //line 12
console.log(this.addSubtractDate.subtract(d, 25, 'days'));
console.log(this.addSubtractDate.add(d, 59, 'minutes'));
} //line 15
```

I however get these compile-time errors:

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(12,1): error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
src/app/app.component.ts(15,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
```

And these errors in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'subtract' of undefined
    at eval (app.component.ts:13)
    at Object.../../../../../src/app/app.component.ts (main.bundle.js:28)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
    at eval (app.module.ts:5)
    at Object.../../../../../src/app/app.module.ts (main.bundle.js:36)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
    at eval (main.ts:4)
    at Object.../../../../../src/main.ts (main.bundle.js:52)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
    at Object.0 (main.bundle.js:67)
```

Could you please tell what is wrong with my code?

And if you have any (other) suggestions regarding how I can access a function that fulfills my purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to import

```
import { add, subtract } from 'add-subtract-date';
```

and then,

```
const d = new Date();
console.log(subtract(d, 25, 'days'));
console.log(add(d, 59, 'minutes'));
```

I personally don't recommend to do this , you can always use native JS to calculate the date.

Comment: Why do not you recommend this method?

Comment: you should not use external library to do simple stuffs, upvote too :)  since you have +15

Comment: Yes it was helpful. Thanks.
The point to me working with pure JS for this particular issue is a big challenge. I have to re-invent the wheel: Write a function for doing all calculations, especially if for example I need to go back 45 days (getting minus as a result!).

Comment: In case I find a ready-made code for this aim, I myself prefer to use that. As I said, going through this is a hassle (at least at first glance).
Thank you again for your patience.